# Vnext Gated checkin builds are waiting for agent

Tags: tfs-2015

we are using TFS2015, newly configured VNext builds with 3 agents.
while manual builds are working fine and able to run in parallel on 3 agents, Gated_Checkin builds are having issues "**Waiting for available agent**" " **Waiting for an agent to be requested**"
i have ruled out that there is an issue with the configuration of the build agents, because the same agents are working as expected with manual builds also when queuing the gated builds manually.
please suggest on this issue.

Comment: Are the gated builds different than the "manual" builds? If so, did you try running them manually?

Comment: yes, gated builds are running fine when queued manually, but are waiting for agent when its queued from developer machines as part of check-in process